Issue with observing SwiftData model and UndoManager
I have created a minimum example to demonstrate an issue with observing SwiftData model and UndoManager. This project includes a simple NavigationSplitView, an Item SwiftData model that is being persisted and an enabled UndoManager.
Problem: The SwiftData model Item can be observed as expected. Changing the date in the DetailView works as expected and all related views (ListElementView + DetailView) are updated as expected. When pressing ⌘+Z to undo with the enabled UndoManager, deletions or inserts in the sidebar are visible immediately (and properly observed by ContentView). However, when changing the timestamp and pressing ⌘+Z to undo that change, it is not properly observed and immediately updated in the related views (ListElementView + DetailView).
Further comments:

Undo operation to the model value changes (here: timestamp) are visible in the DetailView when changing sidebar selections
Undo operation to the model value changes (here: timestamp) are visible in the ListElementView when restarting the app
Undo operation to the model value changes (here: timestamp) are are properly observed and immediately visible in the sidebar, when ommiting the ListElementView (no view encapsulation)

It seems that the UndoManager does not trigger a redraw of the ContentView through the items query?
Relevant code base:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    @State private var selectedItems: Set<Item> = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selectedItems) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ListElementView(item: item)
                        .tag(item)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 180, ideal: 200)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            if let item = selectedItems.first {
                DetailView(item: item)
            } else {
                Text("Select an item")
            }
        }
        .onDeleteCommand {
            deleteSelectedItems()
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteSelectedItems() {
        for selectedItem in selectedItems {
            modelContext.delete(selectedItem)
            selectedItems.remove(selectedItem)
        }
    }
}

struct ListElementView: View {
    @Bindable var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Bindable var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
        
        DatePicker(selection: $item.timestamp, label: { Text("Change Date:") })
    }
}

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}


Always post relevant code as part of the question and not as an external link.

That might be the general rule but in this case we definitely needed the whole project to reproduce and solve the problem.

@malhal https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

@JoakimDanielson: OK, agreed. I have added the most relevant code base.

I see a few mistakes, try this to get it working:
Remove this:
// container.mainContext.undoManager = UndoManager()

And this:
.commands {
    // AppCommands()
}

In ContentView, add this:
@Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager
...
.onChange(of: undoManager, initial: true) {
    modelContext.undoManager = undoManager
}

For the list row either try this:
ListElementView(timestamp: item.timestamp)
    .tag(item)

Or remove .tag() and add this instead:
NavigationLink(value: item) { // sadly causes warning "multiple updates per frame"
    ListElementView(item: item)
}

Depending on which you choose change ListElementView to:
struct ListElementView: View {
    let item: Item
    // or better: let timestamp: Date

Change DetailView to only take what it needs, that is write access to a timestamp, e.g.:
        } detail: {
            if let item = selectedItems.first {
                DetailView(timestamp: Bindable(item).timestamp)
            } else {
                Text("Select an item")
            }
        }

And this:
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var timestamp: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
        DatePicker(selection: $timestamp, label: { Text("Change Date:") })
    }
}

With these fixes, undo is correctly configured on the context, the side bar label updates and detail updates when undo command is sent.
You might have uncovered a bug in Observable by the way, it seems to me detail: { DetailView(item:item) } doesn't call body when item.timestamp changes, but in ListElementView(item: item) it does. detail:  has always been quite badly behaved.
Finally you should change your container init to this to prevent it happening twice if App's body gets recomputed, e.g.
static var persistent: ModelContainer = {
    ...
    }()


OK, I see. Indeed, adding individual binding obviously helps which can be quite nasty when having several parameters in a more complex DetailView.
Thanks for the other hints. NavigationLink is creating an ambiguity towards selectedItems though. It's creating these "multiple updates per frame" warning.

Ok instead of NavigationLink try ListElementView(timestamp: item.timestamp).tag(item) that updates properly and doesn't have the warning. Sadly List on macOS is quite buggy we will need to keep submitting feedback for it ever to be fixed.

I was just thinking we should probably compare the code running on iPad OS to identify where the real bugs on macOS are. It's possible to do command+z with hardware keyboard in simulator. And split view appears in landscape.
